# Six character minimum edit?

Tags: feature-request, editing

Is there a justification for edits having to be 6 characters long?  I tried to correct someone's arithmetic.  They wrote $4 \cdot 8 = 48$. It's a one character change!  (Or 2 if you count insertions and deletions.) To make a six character change doesn't make sense.  I'd have to find some completely gratutitous change to make up the other five (or four) characters.

The question in question is [Tricks for computing things in your head](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/1649/tricks-for-computing-things-in-your-head/1657#1657) .  The error is in the answer that discusses the "vedic" multiplication algorithm.

I can imagine other small edits that would be be useful. E.g., to add a forgotten apostrophe or coma.  (I mean "comma". Woo, good thing I caught that before posting!)

So this is a feature request to reduce the minimum number of changed characters in an edit from 6 to 1.

Comment: I performed the edit you  mention; thanks for pointing it out. But note there are couple other minor things one can do to the post, too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I understand that this can be frustrating and it comes up repeatedly over the sites, but let me try to explain the rationale (even though it is not very relevant on a site as small as ours).

To understand what is going on note that it is not quite the case that every edit must be at least six characters, what is true is that  *a suggested edit* must have this length; user with [the editing privilege](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit), that is 1k here and 2k on graduated sites, can in fact perform shorter edits.

Thus, the idea is to restrict suggested edits in order not to create too much work for those reviewing the edits and to encourage more complete suggested edits.

As I said it would not be much of an issue to have no restriction on our site as the volume is low, but on other sites it could be a problem.

It was asked if this can be changed [Change this behavior to allow for spelling corrections and the like: "Edits must be at least 6 characters"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82534/change-this-behavior-to-allow-for-spelling-corrections-and-the-like-edits-must/82535#82535)
or changed under some restrictions (comparable to the current situation) [Allow under 6 character changes if they are inside code tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76891/allow-under-6-character-changes-if-they-are-inside-code-tags)
or locally [Can minimum character limit or reputation threshold for suggested edits be changed locally (per site)?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/192227/can-minimum-character-limit-or-reputation-threshold-for-suggested-edits-be-chang) 
But it was not changed. Here is some advice how to live with it 
[How to overcome "Edits must be at least 6 characters"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81520/how-to-overcome-edits-must-be-at-least-6-characters)

Comment: Thankfully, I could make a 1-character edit here for "rational" → "rationale".

Comment: I never knew this needs an "e." Thanks for the information.

Comment: +1 as a mod on another board, I need to deal with editor wannabes, offering very minor corrections that satisfy their need for zero typos or exemplary grammar, but they should really participate and wait until they are at 2K. Those will no SE presence and near zero points loading up on edit requests is not my idea of valued member.

Comment: What I'm doing when I encounter these is mention the typo in a comment to the questioner — they can then make the edit without anyone having to approve it, and that's quicker too if they're still online and eager for answers.